# Singular power cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am recently exploring set-theoretical postulates that contradict GCH. One particularly interesting one is the proposition "$2^\kappa$ is singular for each infinite cardinal $\kappa$". However I could not prove that this proposition is at all consistent with ZFC.

It seems that a slightly weakened form "$2^\kappa$ is singular for each infinite *regular* cardinal $\kappa$" is indeed consistent with ZFC, since the function $\kappa\mapsto\aleph_{\kappa^+}$ satisfies the conditions of Easton's theorem and there therefore exists a model where $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\kappa^+}$ for each regular $\kappa$. Can this result also be extended to all singular cardinals?

Comment: Your claim implies the consistency of a large cardinal. For example, Gitik proved that the existence of singular strong limit $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ is equiconsistent with the existence of a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ of Mitchell order $\kappa^{++}$.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma 3.4 in the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07470) by Golshani & Hayut implies that this is consistent relative to the existence of a strong cardinal.

*Golshani, Mohammad; Hayut, Yair*, [**On Foreman’s maximality principle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2016.21), J. Symb. Log. 81, No. 4, 1344-1356 (2016). [ZBL1387.03037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1387.03037).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my question has already been answered in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226887/when-can-power-sets-be-limit-cardinals), where other related topics have also been discussed.